# What happens when Binary Semaphore is Signalled twice? ie. s=1;wait(s); signal(s)signal(s); Does s becomes 0 or it remains 1?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

What happens when Binary Semaphore is Signalled twice? 
i.e. Suppose s is binary semaphore variable with `s=1`

Now we do following--

```
wait(s),signal(s),signal(s)
```

Does s becomes 0 or it remains 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary semaphore would be used to protect some resource, so that only one process may access it at a time.

This process would do a wait, which, assuming the semaphore is 1 (resource isn't already busy) would make the semaphore =0.

When that process is finished with the resource it would signal, allowing other processes access to the resource, making the semaphore =1.

There's no reason why the process would signal twice, nor is there any reason why any other process would signal before doing a wait (let me know if you've thought of one), so two successive signals would be an error. Now if I was writing the OS primitive implementation I'd judge it was a better idea to leave the signal at 1 than to put it to 0 and probably lock the resource out for all time.

The standard texts on semaphores talk about incrementing and decrementing the count, but that's because it's a useful way of thinking about counting semaphores. The way actual semaphores behave in an actual OS when they're used in an odd way depends on the implementation, and is probably not worth examining as a general theory.

Comment: can you explain the reason?? Why can't it be (1+1)%2 to become 0.

Comment: I've re-written the reply with some explanation. Sorry, it was a bit brief.